# Confusion about factorial $\dfrac{(N!)^2}{(2N)!}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, approximation, analytic-number-theory, factorial

I am confused with the expression $\dfrac{(N!)^2}{(2N)!}$. Suppose we write $(2N)!=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\dots p_\ell^{\alpha_\ell}$ and by Hardy-Ramanujan theorem that states that almost all number $n$ has about $\log\log n$ distinct prime factors.

I want to choose large $N$ for which $\ell<2\log\log (2N)!$. I determine the expression, by letting $\beta$ be such that $p^\beta\le 2N<p^{\beta+1}$ corresponding to each $p_i$,
$$\sum_{\alpha\ge 1}\left(2\left\lfloor\dfrac{N}{p^\alpha}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\dfrac{2N}{p^\alpha}\right\rfloor \right)=\sum_{1\le\alpha\le\beta}\left(2\left\lfloor\dfrac{N}{p^\alpha}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\dfrac{2N}{p^\alpha}\right\rfloor \right)\ge\sum_{\alpha\le \beta}\left(-2\right)=-2\beta.$$

Thus, it means $\dfrac{(N!)^2}{(2N)!}\cdot p_1^{2\beta_1}p_2^{2\beta_2}\dots p_\ell^{2\beta_\ell}\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$. However,

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(N!)^2}{(2N)!}\cdot p_1^{2\beta_1}p_2^{2\beta_2}\dots p_\ell^{2\beta_\ell} 
& \le\dfrac{(N!)^2}{(2N)!}\cdot (2N)^{2\ell}\\
& <\dfrac{(N!)^2}{(2N)!}\cdot (2N)^{4\log\log (2N)!}\\
& <\dfrac{(N!)^2}{(2N)!}\cdot (2N)^{4\log(2N\log(2N))}
\end{align*}

and the last one tends to $0$ since $\displaystyle \dfrac{(N!)^2}{(2N)!}\ll \dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{4^N}$ by Stirling approximation, and $\sqrt{N}\cdot(2N)^{4\log(2N\log(2N))}=\text o(4^N)$ because $\log\sqrt{N}+4\log(2N)(\log(2N)+\log\log(2N))=\text o(N)$.

How is this possible? What is my mistake for the argument? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Obviously $\frac {(N!)^2}{(2N)!} = \binom{2N}N ^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, but what about my mistake in the question? @WhatsUp

Comment: You are right that a 'typical' $n$ will have about $\log\log n$ distinct prime factors. But $(2N)!$ is by no means a typical number. In fact, if $n=(2N)!$ then $n$ has $\gg \log n/\log\log n$ many prime factors.

Comment: *I want to choose large N for which $\ell<2\log\log(2N)!$* You cannot choose it that way. The number of prime factors of $(2N)!$ is simply the number of prime numbers between $1$ and $2N$.

Comment: Oh okay thank you. Both of you.